# Storing variables into session but sometimes display empty

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm sorting data using ajax and controller in a session but sometimes it's displaying data and sometimes display empty and I have to use Flash because I want when I back to the home page the session to be empty. How can I solve this?

```
 $(document).on('click', '.btn_getbids', function(e) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }});
   e.preventDefault();
 var form = document.forms.namedItem("booking-form"); 
 var formData = new FormData(form); 
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addItem',
    contentType: false, 
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {   },
    });});
```

**Controller**

```
public function addItem(Request $request) {


$request->session()->flash('country', $request->country);
$request->session()->flash('administrative_area_level_1', $request->administrative_area_level_1);
$request->session()->flash('locality', $request->locality);
    }
```

**Diaplaay  Blade**

```
      <div class="alert alert-success">
                     {{Session::get('country')}} <br>
                      {{Session::get('administrative_area_level_1')}} <br>
                     {{Session::get('locality')}} 

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flash()` will only store data to the session for the next request only

> #### Flash Data
>
> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the flash method. Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted. Flash data is primarily useful for short-lived status messages:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data

You want to use `put()` instead to store it in the session. For example:

```
$request->session()->put('country', $request->country);
```

You can remove a value from the session using `forget()`

```
$request->session()->forget('country');
```

or all using `flush()`

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#deleting-data